# rails list - sort results by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, sorting, date

On my list view I have added .sortdesc to a field I want to order the results by, but if I order by another field, then order by the date again it orders it based on the day, 1-31 and ignores the month and year from the date.

E.G 
05/06/2015, 10/01/2015, 01/10/2015, 03/01/2015

would be ordered

01/10/2015, 03/01/2015, 05/06/2015, 10/01/2015

All I have added to the field on the list view is %th.sortdesc, is there anything else I can use or will I need to add to the controller?

Comment: As far as I know there is no `.sortdesc` in Rails. Do you use a Javascript table framework?

Comment: sorry its not on a field but on a header for a column within the datatable   %table.fullwidth.datatable
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Title
        %th Type
        %th Status
        %th.sortdesc Start date

Comment: I don't know anything about datatables, but the general approach I would take is converting time to an int, compare to sort, reconvert.  It appears they are being sorted as strings currently.  You could also consider adding an html element `data-date` that contains the int version and use that for sorting.